# How do I penalize an orphan brace in a code listing?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, widows-orphans

I want to prevent my code listing and my `tcolorbox` from page breaking and placing only a single brace on the next page. See the image for an example of this.

[image]

The page break in and of itself is fine for large listings, but I think that if TeX were to optimize the spacing, then I could get the closing brace on the same page. Changing the margin sizes will affect all listings (and possibly cause other orphan braces), so I don't really want to do that. I'm not sure if there's a setting in `lstlisting` or `tcolorbox` that will allow me to do this.

Comment: Wait until the book is in final production stage and check carefully for bad page breaks, applying suitable `\enlargethispage` commands or rewording to gain a line.

Comment: Posting a minimal example is more likely to get you help than adding a bounty ;). But it is not clear why you don't try the suggested `\enlargethispage`. You can, in fact, change the margins temporarily with e.g. `changepage`. Whether that is the best solution is a different question.

Comment: `listings` has some limited control on break point, like `breakatwhitespace[=true|false]`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ The problem is that I have the `listings` environment wrapped in a `tcolorbox`. I currently use the `breakable` option in the `tcolorbox` to get the effect that I have now. If I disable that option, it leaves tons of whitespace at the bottom of certain pages. Like @egreg stated, it's probably best if I just wait until the book is almost done and then work on it.

Comment: @TheProgrammer Configuring `listings` globally or for `tcolorbox`es only (through option `/tcb/listings options` or `/tcb/listings options app`, the latter requires `tcolorbox` `hooks` library)) does influence the behavior of `/tcb/breakable` option. Alternatively, you may consider typesetting (not too long) code snippets as floats.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing a break after something is usually pretty easy with TeX, but preventing a break *before* something is often impossible. Here, we're able to hook into `listings` processing commands to inspect the following line before we end the current line so that we can insert a `\penalty` if the next line contains a closing brace.

Warning: this *filled* with dirty tricks, so I wouldn't be surprised if a future update or “interesting” input breaks it somehow.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=2.2in, paperwidth=6in, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Java}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
% Define some constant tokens for later comparisons
\tl_new:N \c__max_end_env_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { } {
    \cA(\\ end \{ lstlisting \})
} \c__max_end_env_tl

\tl_new:N \c__max_close_brace_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { } {
    \cA(\})
} \c__max_close_brace_tl

% Inside an lstlisting environment, at the end of each line, we grab the next
% line and process it.
\def\lst@InitFinalize{
    \__max_make_newline:n {
        \__max_process:n { ##1 }
        \tl_if_eq:NnT \c__max_end_env_tl { ##1 } {
            \__max_reset_newline:
        }
        \lst@MProcessListing ##1 ##2
    }
}

% Process the line. Here, we insert an infinite penalty if the next line
% contains a closing brace.
\newif\ifpreventbreakbeforebrace
\cs_new:Nn \__max_process:n {
    \ifpreventbreakbeforebrace
        \tl_if_in:nVTF { #1 } \c__max_close_brace_tl {
            \hook_gput_next_code:nn { para / after } {
                \penalty20000
            }
        }
    \fi
}

% Auxiliary macros.
\cs_new:Nn \__max_make_newline:n {
    \exp_args:NNo \exp_args:No
        \__max_make_newline_aux_i:nn
        { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 13 } }
        { #1 }
}

\cs_new:Nn \__max_make_newline_aux_i:nn {
    \cs_set:Nn \__max_make_newline_aux_ii:nn { #2 } { #1 }
    \cs_set:Npn #1 ##1 #1 {
        \__max_make_newline_aux_ii:nn { ##1 } { #1 }
    }
}

\cs_new:Nn \__max_reset_newline: {
    \char_set_active_eq:nN { 13 } \scan_stop:
}
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\preventbreakbeforebracefalse
\begin{lstlisting}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\clearpage

\preventbreakbeforebracetrue
\begin{lstlisting}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: output]